# JPaint (Java painting app)

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, graphics

I have this painting app called `JPaint` in Java and I'm wondering if it could be improved. The variable declaration seems repetitive and long, and I think it might be able to be improved.

```
public class JPaint3 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JFrame startFrame;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    private LineBorder border;

    private JRadioButton setRed;
    private JRadioButton setBlue;
    private JRadioButton setYellow;
    private JRadioButton setGreen;
    private JRadioButton setOrange;
    private JRadioButton setPurple;
    private JRadioButton setBlack;
    private JRadioButton setCyan;
    private JRadioButton setPink;
    private JRadioButton setErase;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private JButton fillButton;
        private JButton startButton;
    private JRadioButton setSquare;
    private JRadioButton setCircle;
    private JRadioButton setTriangle;

    private Color dotColor = Color.RED;
        private Graphics graphics = null;
    private ShapeType shapeType = ShapeType.CIRCLE;
    private final Color PURPLE = new Color(80, 0, 80);
        private final Color PINK = new Color(255, 20 , 147);
    private Image logo;

    private static JPaint3 paintApp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        paintApp = new JPaint3();
        paintApp.start();
    }
    public void go(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("JPaint: Version 1.2");
        border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5, true);
        setRed = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
        setBlue = new JRadioButton("Blue", false);
        setYellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow", false);
        setGreen = new JRadioButton("Green", false);
        setOrange = new JRadioButton("Orange", false);
        setPurple = new JRadioButton("Purple", false);
        setBlack = new JRadioButton("Black", false);
        setPink = new JRadioButton("Pink", false);
        setCyan = new JRadioButton("Cyan", false);
        setErase = new JRadioButton("Erase", false);
        clearButton = new JButton("Clear Screen");
        fillButton = new JButton("Fill Screen");
        setSquare = new JRadioButton("Square", false);
        setCircle = new JRadioButton("Circle", true);
        setTriangle = new JRadioButton("Triangle", false);

        setRed.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.RED));
        setBlue.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.BLUE));
        setYellow.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.YELLOW));
        setGreen.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.GREEN));
        setOrange.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.ORANGE));
        setPurple.addItemListener(new ColorListener(PURPLE));
        setBlack.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.BLACK));
        setPink.addItemListener(new ColorListener(PINK));
        setCyan.addItemListener(new ColorListener(Color.CYAN));
        setErase.addItemListener(new EraseListener());

        setSquare.addItemListener(new ShapeListener(ShapeType.SQUARE));
        setCircle.addItemListener(new ShapeListener(ShapeType.CIRCLE));
        setTriangle.addItemListener(new ShapeListener(ShapeType.TRIANGLE));

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ClearListener());
        fillButton.addActionListener(new FillListener());

        ButtonGroup colorsGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        colorsGroup.add(setBlue);
        colorsGroup.add(setRed);
        colorsGroup.add(setYellow);
        colorsGroup.add(setGreen);
        colorsGroup.add(setOrange);
        colorsGroup.add(setPurple);
        colorsGroup.add(setBlack);
        colorsGroup.add(setPink);
        colorsGroup.add(setCyan);
        colorsGroup.add(setErase);

        ButtonGroup shapeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        shapeGroup.add(setSquare);
        shapeGroup.add(setCircle);
        shapeGroup.add(setTriangle);        

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = frame.getContentPane();

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel colors = new JPanel();
        JPanel shapes = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel editPanel = new JPanel();

        editPanel.add(clearButton);
        editPanel.add(fillButton);

        colors.add(setRed);
        colors.add(setBlue);
        colors.add(setYellow);
        colors.add(setGreen);
        colors.add(setOrange);
        colors.add(setPurple);
        colors.add(setBlack);
        colors.add(setPink);
        colors.add(setCyan);
        colors.add(setErase);

        shapes.add(setCircle);
        shapes.add(setSquare);
        shapes.add(setTriangle);

        colors.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        shapes.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        optionPanel.add(colors);

        bottomPanel.add(editPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(shapes);

        optionPanel.setBorder(border);
        bottomPanel.setBorder(border);

        optionPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        editPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        shapes.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        window.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, optionPanel);
        window.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottomPanel);
        window.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        startFrame = new JFrame("Let's Begin!");
        try {
            logo = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("javaLogo.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        startButton = new JButton("Click to begin");
                JLabel label = new JLabel("       JPaint!!!      ");
        Font fancyFont = new Font("Zapfino", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 24);
                Font bigFont = new Font("Chalkboard", Font.BOLD, 30);
        startButton.addActionListener(new StartListener());
        startButton.setFont(fancyFont);
                label.setFont(bigFont);
        startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 50));
        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logo));
        startFrame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, startButton);
                startFrame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, label);
        startFrame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, imgLabel);
        startFrame.pack();
                startFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        startFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class ColorListener implements ItemListener {
        private final Color color;
        public ColorListener(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                dotColor = this.color;
        }

    }
    private class ShapeListener implements ItemListener {
        private final ShapeType type;
        public ShapeListener(ShapeType type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                shapeType = this.type;
        }

    }
    private class ClearListener extends FillListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    Color theDotColor = dotColor;
                    dotColor = Color.WHITE;
                    super.actionPerformed(e);
                    dotColor = theDotColor;
        }

    }
    private class EraseListener extends ColorListener {
        public EraseListener() {
            super(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    private class FillListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Dimension d = frame.getSize();
                        Graphics graphics = drawPanel.getGraphics();
            graphics.setColor(dotColor);
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        }
    }
    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

                @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            graphics = this.getGraphics();
            this.addMouseListener(this);
            this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }
        public void drawShape(int x, int y, ShapeType type) {
                    graphics = this.getGraphics();
                    graphics.setColor(dotColor);
                    if (type == ShapeType.CIRCLE)
                        graphics.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
                    else if (type == ShapeType.SQUARE)
                        graphics.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                    else if (type == ShapeType.TRIANGLE){
                        int[] xValues = {x, x + 10, x + 20};
                        int[] yValues = {y + 20, y, y + 20};
                        graphics.fillPolygon(xValues, yValues, 3);}
                    }

                public void clear() {
                    Dimension d = frame.getSize();
                    Graphics graphics = drawPanel.getGraphics();
                    graphics.setColor(dotColor);
                    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
                }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int mouseX = e.getX();
                int mouseY = e.getY();
                drawShape(mouseX, mouseY, shapeType);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();
            drawShape(mouseX, mouseY, shapeType);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }
    }
    private class StartListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            startFrame.setVisible(false);
            paintApp.go();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You using Java 8?

Comment: Yes. @BoristheSpider

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is damn long, so just a few notes:

Use initializer expressions like

```
private JRadioButton setRed = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
```

Use static *factory* methods to save even more like

```
private JRadioButton setRed = makeColorButton("Red", true, Color.RED);

private static JRadioButton makeColorButton(
        String name, boolean isSet, Color color) {
    JradioButton result = new JRadioButton(name, isSet);
    result.addItemListener(new ColorListener(color));
    return result;
}
```

Actually, I wouldn't bother with `isSet` as it gets used just once.

```
ButtonGroup colorsGroup = new ButtonGroup();
colorsGroup.add(setBlue);
```

Another thing the factory method can do. Just create the group first and pass it to it like

```
private ButtonGroup colorsGroup = new ButtonGroup();
private JRadioButton setRed = makeColorButton("Red", colorsGroup, Color.RED);
```

And yet another such thing:

```
colors.add(setRed);
```

This makes the code surely much shorter, however, I'd strongly recommend to **keep the code short from the very beginning**. Whenever you see, you need to do the same things many times, extract them into a method/class/whatever.

---

```
private class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
```

Use a separate (inner or anonymous) class for the listeners and you can extend `MouseAdapter` and `MouseMotionAdapter` and save yourself the empty methods.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions!  i will wait a little longer before accepting, to see if anyone else has something else…

Comment: @thecoder16 Sure, they will. I haven't even read the code (seriously, I stopped at about `colors` and jumped to the bottom) :D

Answer (score 1):

Some more shortening:

```
    colorsGroup.add(setBlue);
    colorsGroup.add(setRed);
    colorsGroup.add(setYellow);
    colorsGroup.add(setGreen);
    colorsGroup.add(setOrange);
    colorsGroup.add(setPurple);
    colorsGroup.add(setBlack);
    colorsGroup.add(setPink);
    colorsGroup.add(setCyan);
    colorsGroup.add(setErase);
```

Becomes:

```
 for (setter : [setBlue, setRed, setYellow, setGreen,
                setOrange, ..., setErase]) {
     colorsGroup.add(setter);
}
```

Comment: @thecoder16 Note that this can and should be done in `makeColorButton` too.

Comment: @maartinus Ok. Will do!

Comment: @thecoder16 If after you have improved your code you want further suggestions, you can post a follow up question.